# Where is liphone-lib in a unity generated xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, libraries

I am having this strange issue ever since I upgraded my unity. When I build the generated Xcode project I get the following error:

```
 Ld /Users/Ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-arybbykagdcklhdbmekvfmdgxmax/Build/Products/pxelfall.app/pxelfall normal armv7
     cd /Users/Ali/Desktop/Pixel.Fall.iOS-soomla-rollback
     export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.0
     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk
 -L/Users/Ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-arybbykagdcklhdbmekvfmdgxmax/Build/Products
 -L/Users/Ali/SweetPixel/Pixel.Fall/Pixel.Fall/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FacebookSDK
 -L/Users/Ali/Desktop/Pixel.Fall.iOS-soomla-rollback
 -L\"/Users/Ali/Desktop/Pixel.Fall.iOS-soomla-rollback/Libraries\"
 -L/Users/Ali/Desktop/Pixel.Fall.iOS-soomla-rollback/Libraries
 -F/Users/Ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-arybbykagdcklhdbmekvfmdgxmax/Build/Products
 -F/Users/Ali/Desktop/Pixel.Fall.iOS-soomla-rollback/Libraries
 -F/Users/Ali/Desktop/Pixel.Fall.iOS-soomla-rollback
 -filelist /Users/Ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-arybbykagdcklhdbmekvfmdgxmax/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/pxelfall.LinkFileList
 -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -lz -lc++ -framework CoreText -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreData
 -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AddressBook -framework Foundation
 -framework GooglePlayGames -framework UIKit -framework GoogleOpenSource
 -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -liconv.2
 -liPhone-lib -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreLocation
 -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework iAd -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo
 -framework GooglePlus -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics
 -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GameKit -lGoogleAdMobAds -weak-lsqlite3.0 /Users/Ali/SweetPixel/Pixel.Fall/Pixel.Fall/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.a
 -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Social -weak_framework Security -Xlinker -dependency_info
 -Xlinker /Users/Ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-arybbykagdcklhdbmekvfmdgxmax/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/pxelfall_dependency_info.dat
 -o /Users/Ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-arybbykagdcklhdbmekvfmdgxmax/Build/Products/pxelfall.app/pxelfall

 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/Ali/Desktop/Pixel.Fall.iOS-soomla-rollback/Libraries"' ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I cannot find liphone-lib anywhere in the project. I have been able to build this project effortlessly before. I am using unity 4.5.5 and Xcode 6.1

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix it. I had updated to unity 4.5 so it broke my project. I deleted everything and rebuilt again by overwriting old files.  That fixed the error.